# Resize existing library images

Tags: uploads, media-library, images

How can I resize images that were already in the Media Library when I created new custom image sizes? I just want WP to process them as if they're new images, taking into account my new settings, creating versions for the new custom sizes. I'm sure this must be possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the [Force Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/). It will resize all the images and create images according to the size set, what really makes this plugin usefull is that it will delete images of redundant image sizes

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks. That looks good. Interesting that it makes the point of completely deleting the original image to ensure everything is fully resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some intensive Googling I discovered a couple of plugins for just this purpose. This is the one I used:

[Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/)

Comment: This one works very good as well - but I prefer the AJAX version, as the Regenerate Thumbnails one is prone to high memory usage, especially if you regenerate all the thumbnails.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this on your own is actually quite a lot of work. For the sole purpose of regenerating your custom image sizes I would recommend using this plugin:

[AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)

It allows you to loop through your Image Library and regenerate the different image sizes that you selected.

Comment: Hehe, that's the reason I prefer this one :)

Comment: [Force Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/) is also a very useful plugin